# How do I decide if a variable is numeric in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tell if a variable has a numeric value in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647/how-do-i-tell-if-a-variable-has-a-numeric-value-in-perl)

I want to decide if a variable (value parsed from a string) is a number or not. How can I do that? Well, I guess `/^[0-9]+$/` would work, but is there a more elegant version?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if (/\D/)            { print "has nondigits\n" }
if (/^\d+$/)         { print "is a whole number\n" }
if (/^-?\d+$/)       { print "is an integer\n" }
if (/^[+-]?\d+$/)    { print "is a +/- integer\n" }
if (/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) { print "is a real number\n" }
if (/^-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?&\.\d+)$/) { print "is a decimal number\n" }
if (/^([+-]?)(?=\d&\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\d+))?$/)
                     { print "a C float\n" }
```

taken from here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#Perl

Comment: If you insist on a regex, get it from Regexp::Common :)

Comment: And, every one of these regexes that uses the $ anchor allows a newline at the end of the value. That's a mistake in perlfaq4 (I've now patched the docs to remove that mistake), where Rosetta Code got its example. This example, however, was to determine what sort of number it was, not that it was any sort of number.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong - but it seems to me that in the particular case of checking for strictly digits (i.e., subset of numeric, since a numeric can have a decimal point and possibly a negative sign or even a positive sign, and also commas or some other visual grouping character used to group characters in threes for visual reading), then the "/\D/" is - where strings do exist that fail the digits-only test - always more efficient than "/^\d+$/" because "/\D/" is true on the scan of the first non-digit character.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `looks_like_number()` function from the core [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util) module.
See also the question in perlfaq: [How do I determine whether a scalar is a number/whole/integer/float?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number/whole/integer/float?)

Comment: This is arguably the most correct answer, since `Scalar::Util` hooks into the Perl API to actually ask Perl whether it thinks the variable looks numeric.  Thus, for the common task of avoiding 'numeric' warnings, this will always work.  Of course, sometimes it's better to simply say `no warnings 'numeric';`...

Answer (score 9):

**Using regex, it's good to use:**

```
sub is_int { 
    $str = $_[0]; 
    #trim whitespace both sides
    $str =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;          

    #Alternatively, to match any float-like numeric, use:
    # m/^([+-]?)(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\d+))?$/

    #flatten to string and match dash or plus and one or more digits
    if ($str =~ /^(\-|\+)?\d+?$/) {
        print "yes  " . $_[0] . "\n";
    }
    else{
        print "no   " . $_[0] . "\n";
    }
}
is_int(-12345678901234);     #yes
is_int(-1);                  #yes
is_int(23.);                 #yes
is_int(-23.);                #yes
is_int(0);                   #yes
is_int(+1);                  #yes
is_int(12345678901234);      #yes
is_int("\t23");              #yes
is_int("23\t");              #yes
is_int("08");                #yes
is_int("-12345678901234");   #yes
is_int("-1");                #yes
is_int("0");                 #yes
is_int("+1");                #yes
is_int("123456789012345");   #yes
is_int("-");                 #no
is_int("+");                 #no 
is_int("yadz");              #no
is_int("");                  #no
is_int(undef);               #no
is_int("- 5");               #no
is_int("+ -5");              #no
is_int("23.1234");           #no
is_int("23.");               #no
is_int("--1");               #no
is_int("++1");               #no
is_int(" 23.5 ");            #no
is_int(".5");                #no
is_int(",5");                #no
is_int("%5");                #no
is_int("5%");                #no
```

**Alternatively, you can use POSIX.**

```
use POSIX;

if (isdigit($var)) {
    // integer
}
```

Comment: This just finds digits. It misses literals that are numbers that have more than mere digits.

Comment: Is POSIX part of core perl?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html :
This function has been removed as of v5.24. It was very similar to matching against qr/ ^ [[:digit:]]+ $.