# Perl, how to determine if a variable value is a number?

Tags: regex, perl, numbers, perl-module

Is there a unique method to determine if a variable value is 
a number, Since the values could be in scientific notation as well (for example, 5.814e-10)?

Comment: "is there unique method" — no, this is Perl, TMTOWTDI! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell if a variable has a numeric value in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647/how-do-i-tell-if-a-variable-has-a-numeric-value-in-perl)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The core module `Scalar::Util` exports `looks_like_number()`, which gives access to the underlying Perl API.

> `looks_like_number EXPR`
>
> Returns true if perl thinks `EXPR` is a number.

Answer (score 16):

From perlfaq4:[How do I determine whether a scalar is a number/whole/integer/float](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number/whole/integer/float?)?

```
    if (/\D/)            { print "has nondigits\n" }
    if (/^\d+$/)         { print "is a whole number\n" }
    if (/^-?\d+$/)       { print "is an integer\n" }
    if (/^[+-]?\d+$/)    { print "is a +/- integer\n" }
    if (/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) { print "is a real number\n" }
    if (/^-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$/) { print "is a decimal number\n" }
    if (/^([+-]?)(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\d+))?$/)
            { print "a C float\n" }
```

There are also some commonly used modules for the task.

`Scalar::Util` (distributed with 5.8) provides access to perl's internal function `looks_like_number` for determining whether a variable looks like a number.

`Data::Types` exports functions that validate data types using both the above and other regular expressions.

Thirdly, there is `Regexp::Common` which has regular expressions to match various types of numbers.

Those three modules are available from the CPAN

Answer (score 9):

There are also [String::Numeric](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-Numeric/lib/String/Numeric.pm) and [Regexp::Common::number](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/lib/Regexp/Common/number.pm) .. looks handy.

String::Nummeric also has a ["a comparison with Scalar::Util::looks_like_number()"](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-Numeric/lib/String/Numeric.pm#COMPARISON)

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from an answer in *[How do I tell if a variable has a numeric value in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647/how-do-i-tell-if-a-variable-has-a-numeric-value-in-perl)*–

```
for my $testable ( qw( 1 5.25 0.001 1.3e8 foo bar 1dd 0 ) )
{
    printf("%10s %s a number\n",
           $testable,
           isa_number($testable) ? "is" : "isn't")
}

sub isa_number {
    use warnings FATAL => qw/numeric/;
    my $arg = shift;
    return unless defined $arg;
    eval { $arg + 0; 1 };
}
```

Comment: Your `isa_number` thinks `'0'` isn't a number.