# Validate data from JSON having Boolean(true,false) not ("true","false"). And string ("12345") not (12345)

Tags: json, perl

Need to validate the data form JSON file.
Example JSON:
Expected

```
{
   id => "12345",
   flag=> true
}
```

I need to throw error if the file having data like below

```
{
   id => 12345,
   flag=> "true"
}
```

I found this link for validating the string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647/how-do-i-tell-if-a-variable-has-a-numeric-value-in-perl)

But if there any other solution, it would be helpful for me.
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is `$val` a String?**

The linked answer won't help you differentiate `"12345"` from `12345`. To check if a value is stored as a string, you can use

```perl
use B qw( svref_2object SVf_POK );

svref_2object(\$val)->FLAGS & SVf_POK
   or die("Not a string\n");
```

This should work for the values from your JSON parser, but it won't work if you can expect dual vars, objects with overloads or magical scalars.

---

**Is `$val` a Boolean?**

The most popular JSON parsers use special objects to represent `true` and `false` in JSON.

With Cpanel::JSON::XS, you can use

```perl
Cpanel::JSON::XS::is_bool($val)
   or die("Not a boolean\n");
```

JSON::XS and JSON::PP also provide some means of checking.